# pyenv deletes python after installing

Tags: python, software-installation, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I try installing python with

```
pyenv install 3.11.0
```

(though this happens no matter the version) on my Raspberry Pi. When the install is running, there's a `3.11.0` directory in `~/.pyenv/versions`, `pyenv versions` recognizes it, and **the installed python is actually usable**, but the dir disappears after the installation process finished.

Raspberry Pi OS bullseye on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3

Aside from one time when it errored out, this has happened every time I tried installing, including 3.11, 3.10, 3.9 and 3.8

I have tried:

- Installing `python` 3.11, 3.10, 3.9 and 3.8, so I dont think it will work with any other version
- Reinstalling `pyenv` and its dependencies multiple times

Comment: @Milliways - `WHY?` why does one need to justify the version of Python they wish to use? - `you NEED to build it from source.` Which is what pyenv install does.

Comment: @Milliways why would having an existing python **delete another python**?

Comment: [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60862335/what-happens-if-i-use-update-alternatives-to-manage-python-versions-instead-of-v)

Comment: @Seamus what does that have to do with this problem?

Comment: Maybe nothing...

Comment: Not a Raspberry Pi question, its a Unix/Linux question.